# Memory leaks caused by bitmaps in Android's layouts

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap, garbage-collection

I'm trying to figure out why the bitmaps of my apps (used just in the xml layouts) never get recycled, so after the user navigates across 10/12 pages the app crashes with outofmemoryexception.

I tried to analyze the memory usage using Mat and I can find every single bitmap in the Retained Heap.

Here is how images are used in the XML layout (about 1 per layout):

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="2000dp"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
android:src="@drawable/welcome"/>
```

And here is the  relevant activity code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.splash);

     ImageView but = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            { 
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EtaActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);    
                finish();
            }
        };

        but.setOnClickListener(listener); 
 }

public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use Image Loader

[1) Universal image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: How is this connected to the need of having images in the XML layout? I use things like image loader wehen I have to dinamically load images in my app, not when a static image is used as background.

Comment: imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);